# Check Cognito Domain prefix availability using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-route53

Im creating Cognito userpool and Userpool Clientapp using SDK. before creating these I"ll have to check whether given domain prefixes available or not. How do I check domain prefix availability using sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an API for that in the SDK, but you can just query the DNS to check if an alias is available:

The domain is:

`<custom-prefix>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com`

If DNS responds with an A record it means that the name is not available.

For example, `user-pool` in Sydney region is not available:

```
$ dig A user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> A user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18440
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com. 44 IN A 13.54.55.18
user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com. 44 IN A 3.24.31.222
user-pool.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com. 44 IN A 52.64.160.14

;; Query time: 183 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.6#53(192.168.3.6)
;; WHEN: Mon May 18 17:37:55 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```